# Why do some Python functions have an extra set of parenthesis around the argument list?

Tags: python, arguments, parentheses

I've seen some Python functions written like this:

```
def get_year((year,prefix,index,suffix)):
  return year
```

How does that differ (if at all) from other functions without the extra parentheses like this:

```
def do_format(yr,pfx,id,sfx):
  return "%s %s %s/%s"%(yr, id, pfx, sfx)
```

Or is it just a matter of taste in styles, or if they differ, can get_year() be rewritten to be in the style of do_format() or vice-versa without effecting existing caller's syntax?

Comment: Tuple unpacking, the ole standby.

Comment: Note that this feature is, thankfully, gone in Python 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `get_year` function in your example uses an automatically unpacked tuple parameter (this is the feature gone from Python 3).  To call it, you give it a single parameter, and that parameter is expected to be a sequence containing four values.

```
# Invocation
my_input = [2013, 'a', 'b', 'c'] # sequence does NOT have to be a tuple!
my_year = get_year(my_input) # returns 2013
```

To rewrite this for Python 3 but not alter the invocation (in other words, to not break existing code which calls `get_year`):

```
def get_year(input_sequence):
    year, prefix, index, suffix = input_sequence
    return year
```

The above is essentially what tuple unpacking is doing for you automatically.  In this particular case, you could simply write

```
def get_year(input_sequence):
    return input_sequence[0]
```

For further information, read [PEP 3113](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

Comment: +1 Perfect. Now I got what OP was actually asking. Looks like I myself was getting confused. :( Sorry OP.

Comment: Till now I was working only on Python 2.7. But now I think, it's really time to move onto Python 3.x. :)

Answer (score 10):

The first function takes a single tuple argument, whereas the second function takes 4 arguments. You can pass those parameters individually, or as a tuple with `splat` operator, that will unpack the tuple into individual parameters.

E.g:

```
# Valid Invocations
print do_format(*('2001', '234', '12', '123'))  # Tuple Unpacking
print do_format('2001', '234', '12', '123')     # Separate Parameter
print get_year(('2001', '234', '12', '123'))

# Invalid invocation. 
print do_format(('2001', '234', '12', '123'))   # Passes tuple
```

Comment: How would you rewrite the tuple unpacking function to not use that feature?

Comment: @WilliamKF. I don't understand. What feature? If you don't want to do tuple unpacking, then just pass them as tuple as in first function.

Comment: @WilliamKF To write `get_year` in the form of `do_format`, just remove those brackets. That's all.

Comment: Above someone writes that tuple packing is gone in Python v3, so how would you rewrite the function so that callers would not have to change but it would work in Python v3?

Comment: @WilliamKF. First of all you are confusing yourself with which one uses tuple unpacking. It's the 2nd function that uses it. In your edited question, you are talking about changing the first function, that is fine even in Python 3. Now, as far as changing the 2nd functino, without affecting the way callers invoke it, that's not possible. Because tuple unpacking is done due to some changes done in the way the parameters are passed. So, your caller should not use `splat` operator to unpack in the 2nd function, rather just pass them as separate arguments as in the 2nd example.

Comment: @RohitJain: I'm not sure who is confused. For one thing, "first" and "second" mean different things depending on whether you are looking at the text of the OP's question or the text of your answer. For another, the "tuple unpacking" referred to by Martijn in the main comments specifically refers to the *definition* of a function, and I think you are either talking about the invocation, or sometimes the invocation and sometimes the definition. So that everyone is on the same page, let's all look at [PEP 3113](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

Comment: @JohnY. So, it is like both the function is using tuple unpacking. In one, it's explicit (When I invoke it with splat operator on tuple), and the other one is doing is behind the scenes. Is this what is happening?

Comment: @JohnY. Oh! Didn't notice that I've changed the order of functions in my answer, that might have confused you. But, I was referring to the first function in my answer. I didn't knew `get_year` also uses `tuple unpacking` and then `repacking` behind the scene. So, my whole argument in the last comment to William seems wrong. :(

Answer (score 1):

These are all equivalent (the caller will not have to change):

```
# 2.x unpacks tuple as part of the function call, 3.x raises exception
def get_year((year,prefix,index,suffix)):
    """get year from (year, prefix, index, suffix) tuple"""
    return year

# 2.x and 3.x, you unpack tuple in the function call
def get_year(year_tuple):
    """get year from (year, prefix, index, suffix) tuple"""
    year, prefix, index, suffix = year_tuple
    return year

# 2.x and 3.x, speedier because you don't unpack what you don't need
def get_year(year_tuple):
    """get year from (year, prefix, index, suffix) tuple"""
    return year_tuple[0]
```